# Binary strings recursive function

Tags: python, binary

How to write a recursive function that generates a list of binary of length n with a specified number of 1s?
Here's a code that generates recursively a list of binarys; without a specified number of 1s:

```
def generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, i):  

    if i == n: 
        printTheArray(arr, n)  
        return

    # First assign "0" at ith position  
    # and try for all other permutations  
    # for remaining positions  
    arr[i] = 0
    generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, i + 1)  

    # And then assign "1" at ith position  
    # and try for all other permutations  
    # for remaining positions  
    arr[i] = 1
    generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, i + 1)
```

*Taken from geeksforgeeks*

Comment: This function is already recursive. What precisely is the issue?

Comment: Check out this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847310/equation-for-generating-integers-for-n-bit-binary-strings-with-k-bits-set-to-1

Comment: Did you check the accepted answer? It defines a recursive function.

Comment: Hint: Pass the number of 1's remaining in the function call too, and bail out if there are more 1's than digits left.

Comment: Thanks DroidX86 and Ken Shiriff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
def binaryStrings(n, ones):  
    if n < ones: # impossible
        return []
    if n == ones:
        return ["1" * ones]
    if ones == 0:
        return ["0" * n]
    a = binaryStrings(n-1, ones)
    b = binaryStrings(n-1, ones-1)
    return ["0"+s for s in a] + ["1"+s for s in b]
```

Example call to get all 6-digit binary numbers which have exactly 4 1-digits:

```
print(binaryStrings(6,4))
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate all possible sequences with adding a 0 or a 1 at each position. Total possible sequences = 2^MAX. Keep track of the number of 1s in the current sequence so far to break.

```
# Generate all binary numbers with exactly "n" 1s
# Max digits in the binary number = MAX

def binary(n):
    MAX = 5
    all_solutions = []
    def solve(current, remaining_ones):
        if len(current) > MAX:
            return
        if remaining_ones == 0:
            all_solutions.append(current+"0"*(MAX-len(current)))
            return

        solve(current+"1", remaining_ones - 1)
        solve(current+"0", remaining_ones)

    solve("", n)
    return all_solutions

 print(binary(2))
 # ['11000', '10100', '10010', '10001', '01100', '01010', '01001', '00110', '00101', '00011']
```